# Does .find() go from the element it's used on, or from document start down?

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
$.fn.search = function ()
{
    $(document).on('change', 'input, select', function() {
        $(this).find('.step').data('changed', 1);
    });
};

$.fn.search();
```

as you can all it does is, listen for changes on inputs and selects (dynamically created - hence the `$(document)` and when a change is found add a data tag to the closest div.

However it's not assigning the data tag.

this implies to me that `.find()` searches from the element down rather than the document start. Is this the case or is it just my code is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method search for the descendant element instead of that use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the closest ancestor.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input, select', function() {
    $(this).closest('.step').data('changed', 1);
});
```

Comment: The important point here being the 'this' inside a delegate binding is the element the event originated from, not the parent element the delegate binding is bound to.